# How to use data binding for Switch onCheckedChageListener event?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-switch

As question indicates, how to bind checked change listener to Switch button in xml ?

I am not using recycler view. Just a simple layout.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with setting it dynamically?

Comment: Can we use same view model else where in project with observable fields using disk cache?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it with a method reference:

```
<CheckBox android:onCheckedChanged="@{callback::checkedChangedListener}".../>
```

or with a lambda expression if you want to pass different parameters:

```
<CheckBox android:onCheckedChanged="@{() -> callback.checked()}".../>
```

Comment: This is not working for me i get `Unknown attribute android:onCheckedChanged`

Comment: @TiagoOliveira although I'm also getting that warning, after launching the app it seems to work indeed

Comment: @GeorgeMount why we can't use app:onCheckedChangeListener to call method setOnCheckedChangeListener in CheckBox?

Answer (score 52):

Using lambda expression and a `Switch`:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(boolean checked) {
     // implementation      
}
```

XML file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{(switch, checked) -> item.onCheckedChanged(checked)}"
    ...
/>
```

Where `item` is the class that implements `onCheckedChange` method and is imported to the XML file like this:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="yourClass"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Can we create a custom 2-way binding which would reduce the boilerplate

Comment: @AdityaLadwa what's wrong with using `checked` attribute? you can bind that pretty easily

Comment: But after using this, if I try to check my switch programmatically using the binding.mySwitch.setChecked(true), the item.onCheckedChanged method is not getting called !!!

Comment: Cannot find a setter for <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial app:onCheckedChanged> that accepts parameter type 'lambda'

Answer (score 29):

### Different Ways

#### (1) Set by [method expression](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)

**In layout**

```
<variable
    name="activity"
    type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.activities.CalendarActivity"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={model.checked}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{activity::onGenderChanged}"
    />
```

**In Activity**

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCalendarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.activity = this
        binding.model = Model()
    }

    fun onGenderChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean) {
        println("buttonView = [$buttonView], isChecked = [$isChecked]")
    }
}
```

#### (2) Set by [lambda expression](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) and method call

```
<variable
    name="model"
    type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.data.Model"/>

<variable
    name="activity"
    type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.activities.HomeActivity"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={model.checked}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{(button, bool)-> activity.saveGender(bool)}"
    />
```

In Activity

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCalendarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.activity = this
        binding.model = Model()
    }

    fun saveGender(isChecked: Boolean) {
        println("isChecked = [$isChecked]")
    }
}
```

#### (3) Pass `OnCheckedChangeListener` anonymous class to layout

```
<variable
    name="onGenderChange"
    type="android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={model.checked}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{onGenderChange}"
    />
```

In Activity

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCalendarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.model = Model()
        binding.setOnGenderChange { buttonView, isChecked ->
            println("buttonView = [$buttonView], isChecked = [$isChecked]")
        }
    }
}
```

#### (4) Pass `OnCheckedChangeListener` by reference

```
<variable
    name="onGenderChange2"
    type="android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={model.checked}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{onGenderChange2}"
    />
```

Activity

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCalendarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.model = Model()
        binding.onGenderChange2 = onGenderChange
    }

    private val onGenderChange: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener = CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        println("buttonView = [$buttonView], isChecked = [$isChecked]")
    }
}
```

#### Now below will NOT work

Now if you set `CheckChangeListener` in code that will not work. because you can't set two callback on one component. One callback is already set by binding, so your callback in code will not work.

```
binding.mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
    println("buttonView = [$buttonView], isChecked = [$isChecked]")
}
```

[Check **CompoundButtonBindingAdapter** class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/3b920788e90bb0abe615a5d5c899915f0014444b/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/CompoundButtonBindingAdapter.java) to see how Switch Binding works.

Comment: The last statement saved my day. Apparently I had 2 listeners on a RadioGroup and was wondering why the binding implementation wasn't working

Comment: Is there a way to do this just using xml? I.e. if I have a SwitchPreference in an xml and I want it to use a custom layout `android:layout="@layout/custom"` and pass that layout a data-bound title "passedTitle", I can do it successfully using <include> as follows: `<include layout="@layout/custom"  bind:passedTitle="@{@string/title}" />`, but it doesn't do anything (I get `attribute passedTitle not found`) if I just do it in the preference:  `<SwitchPreference
    android:key="@string/key"
    layout="@layout/custom"
    bind:passedTitle="@{@string/title}"`

Comment: Beautiful answer.used the last one

Comment: To bad, I can't give plus one for each solution you submitted.

Comment: you don't need to reference activity, `android:onCheckedChanged` should trigger a request in viewModel

Answer (score 4):

Simply use ViewModel, liveData and Transformations
first on your ViewModel

```
var availabilityState = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)
val availabilityText :LiveData<String> =Transformations.map(availabilityState)
{
    if (it == true)
    {
        "Available"
    }else
    {
      "Not Available"
    }
}
```

Then on your XML use

```
<Switch
android:checked="@={addBookViewModel.availabilityState}"
android:text="@{addBookViewModel.availabilityText}"
...>
```

That is it.

Comment: Also works with androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat