# android databinding: how to avoid onCheckedChanged triggered by programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox, data-binding, android-databinding

I am now trying to use android data-binding in my project, and encounter this kind of issue, for example: I have 3 checkbox as a checkbox group, if first checkbox is checked, then a variable `type` is 1. the second makes `type` to 2, the 3rd makes `type` to 3. so I implement the code in this way.

```
   // layout.xml


   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:checked="@{userInfoViewModel.type == 1}"
        android:onCheckedChanged="@{(compoundButton, checked) -> userInfoViewModel.onTypeChecked(checked, 1)}"
        />

   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:checked="@{userInfoViewModel.type == 2}"
        android:onCheckedChanged="@{(compoundButton, checked) -> userInfoViewModel.onTypeChecked(checked, 2)}"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:checked="@{userInfoViewModel.type == 3}"
        android:onCheckedChanged="@{(compoundButton, checked) -> userInfoViewModel.onTypeChecked(checked, 3)}"
        />
```

---

```
// viewModel

public void onTypeChecked(boolean checked, int i) {
    if (checked) {
        // if it is a check. set the type
        type.set(i);
    } else {
        // if it is a uncheck. set type to unknown
        type.set(0);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that, if I have checked 1st checkbox, then I check the 2nd. `type` should be set to 2, and the UI should update correctly. But the reality is that `uncheck` event also occur on the 1st checkbox, after `type` is set to 2, then `type.set(0)` is triggered, so no checkbox is checked.

In fact, this issue is same to [onCheckedChanged called automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641705/oncheckedchanged-called-automatically). What I need is a solution for data-binding.

In non-data-binding project, I think the best solution is using `setCheckedSilent`(answer by @Emanuel Andrada).

```
  public void setCheckedSilent(boolean checked) {
    super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    super.setChecked(checked);
    super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
}
```

But in data-binding, I can not do this. So is there any expert can help me out?

According to @Arpan Sharma's answer, listen to `onClick` instead of `onCheckedChanged`. This solution works currently, But I am worried about the value of `checked`, is it always right?

```
public void onTypeChecked(View view, int i) {
    Boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    if (checked) {
        type.set(i);
    } else {
        type.set(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same problem and i used onCLick listener instead onCHeck 
listener .That way the listener wont change the check state when it is set programatically.
In your problem you should try setting different check change listeners to your check boxes.

Comment: So how can you distinct it is check or uncheck? get the current state when handle it? It should be able to work. BTW, Google is so stupid? No elegance solution？

Comment: I have tried your solution(check the update of the question), it works in my environment. But I am considering wether the state of the checkbox can always right. When the click callback is triggered, the checkbox's state is always updated?

Comment: yes the state of the check box will be changed automatically,Inside the listener you will have to check its state and then act accordingly.

Comment: It will be check/uncheck on every click.Not to worry

Comment: Yeah, the state should change every time, but what I am worried about is that: Does the state change always happen before onclick callback is invoked.

Comment: OK. Thank you, just wait for several days. If no better answer, I will choose you as answer.

Answer (score 16):

Expose an ObservableBoolean from the ViewModel, then use two-way databinding over that boolean.

Then you can use the ObservableBoolean's values to decide what you want to do, rather than encode it in the XML.

```
android:checked="@={vm.checkedValue}"
```

Comment: Please, show some code. I can't understand, what have you done?

Comment: @CoolMind the missing code is just `private val observableBoolean = ObservableBoolean(false)`

Answer (score 8):

This is very simple with data binding

In xml checkbox component

```
 <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{(compoundButton, checked) -> 
changeKeyboardVM.onCheckedChange(compoundButton, checked)}" />
```

In ViewModel or Activity

```
  public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton button, boolean check) {
    Log.d("Z1D1", "onCheckedChange: " + check);
}
```

now Boolean check `true` on checked
and `false` on unchecked

Comment: You didn't solve the problem as you didn't set `android:checked`.

Answer (score 7):

I came across this question for first time and I think it's better to be implemented using binding adapter.

Here is the code for binding adapter

```
interface OnUserCheckedChangeListener {
    fun onUserCheckChange(view:CompoundButton, isChecked:Boolean)
}
@BindingAdapter("onUserCheckedChange")
fun setUserCheckedChangeListener(view:CompoundButton, listener: OnUserCheckedChangeListener?){
    if(listener == null){
        view.setOnClickListener(null)
    }else{
        view.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onUserCheckChange(view, view.isChecked)
        }
    }
}
```

And we can use it on any compound button

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/finish_check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"   
            android:checked="@{your_condition}"
            onUserCheckedChange="@{(view, checked) -> vm.onItemChecked(todo, checked)}"
            />
```

Comment: How does it help? Is `onUserCheckedChange` called after `android:checked` set? Does it raise `onCheckedChanged` event when swipe?

Answer (score 1):

Using `onClick` instead of `onCheckedChanged` to prevent 2-ways binding.

**From `item_order_view.xml`:**

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.package.name.OrderItemViewModel" />
</data>

           <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_selected"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/white"
                android:checked="@{viewModel.isSelect}"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onClickedCheckBox()}"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

**From `OrderItemViewModel.java`**

```
public class OrderItemViewModel {

    public final ObservableField<Boolean> isSelect;
    public final OrderItemViewModelListener mListener;
    private final Order mOrder;

    public OrderItemViewModel(Order order, OrderItemViewModelListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mOrder = order;

        isSelect = new ObservableField<>(mOrder != null ? mOrder.isSelect() : false);
    }

    /**
     * Using onClick instead of onCheckedChanged
     * to prevent 2-ways binding issue.
     */
    public void onClickedCheckBox() {
        mListener.onCheckChanged();
    }

    public interface OrderItemViewModelListener {
        void onCheckChanged();
    } 
}
```

Comment: How do you process swipe?

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52606437/2914140:

Write inside `OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
if (button.isPressed()) {
    // A user pressed Switch.
}
```

Maybe some answers from [How to use data binding for Switch onCheckedChageListener event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268572/how-to-use-data-binding-for-switch-oncheckedchagelistener-event) may help, for instance, defining `android:onCheckedChanged` listener, but I didnt test.